# res.direct() isn't working with latest mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman

I've been making a url shortener and figured out that res.redirect() is giving me an error.
The code:

```
const express = require("express");
const { connectMongoDB } = require("./connection");
const urlRouter = require("./routes/url");
const URL = require("./model/url");
const app = express();
const PORT = 8001;

connectMongoDB("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/short-url");

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/url", urlRouter);

app.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const shortId = req.params.id;
    const entry = await URL.findOne({ shortId });
    console.log("entry:", entry);
    return res.redirect(303, entry.redirectURL);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Sever started listening at ${PORT}`);
});
```

The error:

[error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2jmU.png)

It gets solved in postman when I use OFF Automatically follow redirects.

Can someone help me how to make it work on browser??

[postman settings change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhtVa.png)

Comment: Is your code ending up in the `get` endpoint a second time and, correctly, failing to find a document with full URL? Perhaps the redirect is incorrectly sending the user back to the same domain rather than sending them out to the full URL? Separately, your code should probably have logic to handle a missing/incorrect short URL rather than crashing

Comment: Yep. even I felt the same, but surprisingly it works perfectly fine for the youtuber from whom I followed along to write the code

Comment: The fact that it works somewhere else suggests there is some difference. Either in the code or in the sample being used or something else. Doesn't change the fact that you need to make some adjustment to your configuration. Did it ever work for you? Eg before upgrading MongoDB? I don't think the database is the problem here in any way

Comment: It's working completely fine now on changing the redirect address to full URL. Thanks:)